# Populate treeview wthout parentid field

Tags: c#, treeview

This is my table

```
ID     SubID 
============
1      1001    
1      4432     
1      2345      
1      6322    
2      2014     
2      5432
```

The final result in treeview list should be

1
--1001
--4432
--2345
--6322
2
--2014
--5432

How to do that? Those data are stored in DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "key" of a node and check if it exists.  If it doesn't, add it, then you can reference that key to add the child nodes:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows) {
  if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(dr["ID"].ToString())) {
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["ID"].ToString(), dr["ID"].ToString());
  }
  treeView1.Nodes[dr["ID"].ToString()].Nodes.Add(dr["SubID"].ToString());
}
```